# std::vector of vectors deallocates its shared_ptr content (incorrect usage of stack solid objects?)

Tags: c++, stack, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, stdvector

Vector of vectors of shared_ptr deallocates its Piece instances.
I created it in my Board class like this:

```
std::vector < std::vector < std::shared_ptr <Piece> > > board;
```

But it deallocates each time the inner cycle leaves the scope:

```
Board::board with capacity 10 size: 10
Piece born 0x7faedbc1dc78
Row 0 Column 0 piece0x7faedbc1dc78
Piece born 0x7faede303fd8
Row 1 Column 0 piece0x7faede303fd8
Piece born 0x7faede30d2a8
Row 2 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d2a8
Piece born 0x7faede30d248
Row 3 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d248
Piece born 0x7faede30d348
Row 4 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d348
Piece born 0x7faede30d368
Row 5 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d368
Piece born 0x7faede30d4c8
Row 6 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d4c8
Piece born 0x7faede30d4e8
Row 7 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d4e8
Piece born 0x7faede30d508
Row 8 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d508
Piece born 0x7faede30d528
Row 9 Column 0 piece0x7faede30d528
Piece death 0x7faede30d528
Piece death 0x7faede30d508
Piece death 0x7faede30d4e8
Piece death 0x7faede30d4c8
Piece death 0x7faede30d368
Piece death 0x7faede30d348
Piece death 0x7faede30d248
Piece death 0x7faede30d2a8
Piece death 0x7faede303fd8
Piece death 0x7faedbc1dc78
Piece born 0x7faede303fd8
Row 0 Column 1 piece0x7faede303fd8
Piece born 0x7faede30d2a8
Row 1 Column 1 piece0x7faede30d2a8
Piece born 0x7faede30d248
Row 2 Column 1 piece0x7faede30d248
Piece born 0x7faedbe7db98
Row 3 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe7db98
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f6a8
Row 4 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f6a8
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f868
Row 5 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f868
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f888
Row 6 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f888
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f8a8
Row 7 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f8a8
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f8c8
Row 8 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f8c8
Piece born 0x7faedbe8f8e8
Row 9 Column 1 piece0x7faedbe8f8e8
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f8e8
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f8c8
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f8a8
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f888
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f868
Piece death 0x7faedbe8f6a8
Piece death 0x7faedbe7db98
Piece death 0x7faede30d248
Piece death 0x7faede30d2a8
Piece death 0x7faede303fd8
Piece born 0x7faedbe7db98
Row 0 Column 2 piece0x7faedbe7db98 ...
```

Heres the Board class code:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Board::Board(int width_, int height_) : width(width_), height(height_), board(height)
{
    cout << "Board::board with capacity " << board.capacity() << " size: " << board.size() << endl;
//    board = vector< vector < shared_ptr < Piece >>> (height) ;

    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        vector < shared_ptr < Piece > > row(width);
        board[i] = row;

        for (int j=0;j<width;j++) {
            shared_ptr< Piece > piece = make_shared<Piece>();
            row[j] = piece;
            cout << "Row " << j << " Column " << i << " piece" << &*piece << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant Piece code (basically it just squacks)

```
class Piece {
public:
    Piece() { std::cout << "Piece born " << this << std::endl;}
    ~Piece() { std::cout << "Piece death " << this << std::endl;}
    Piece(const Piece &rhs) {
        std::cout << "Piece copy " << this << " from " << &rhs << std::endl;
    }
    Piece & operator=(const Piece & rhs) {
        std::cout << "Piece assigned " << this << " from " << &rhs << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

No copy or assign operators are invoked. So I believe its NOT due to vector self-reallocation because I pre-allocated outermost vector in Board's constructor (as well as local vector allocated to "width" in inner cycle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
board[i] = row;
```

This copies the contents of the `row` vector *at the time of the assignment* into `board[i]`. Then, you proceed to fill the local `row` vector, but do nothing more with it.

Move the assignment until after loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    vector < shared_ptr < Piece > > row(width);

    for (int j=0;j<width;j++) {
        shared_ptr< Piece > piece = make_shared<Piece>();
        row[j] = piece;
        cout << "Row " << j << " Column " << i << " piece" << &*piece << endl;
    }
    board[i] = std::move(row);
}
```

Alternatively, to get rid of the assignment altogether, you could introduce `row` as simply an alias:

```
for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    auto &row = board[i];
    row.resize(width);

    for (int j=0;j<width;j++) {
        shared_ptr< Piece > piece = make_shared<Piece>();
        row[j] = piece;
        cout << "Row " << j << " Column " << i << " piece" << &*piece << endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to streamline the code even more, you can do this (I would even say it's clearer):

```
for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    auto &row = board[i];

    for (int j=0;j<width;j++) {
        row.emplace_back(make_shared<Piece>());
        cout << "Row " << j << " Column " << i << " piece" << row.back().get() << endl;
    }
}
```

Notice that `std::shared_ptr::get()` returns the raw pointer, and I personally find it preferable to `&*`.

Comment: oh, thanks! :) I'm coming from the world of Objective C where everything is a pointer so order no matters at all. Thanks to your answer, its obvious to me now that Row stack object's content is copied so there are TWO separate instances (And I work only with local stack one NOT one residing in vector). I begin to question the memory efficiency of this approach (don't like the idea of spawning too many instances). Of course I always could use raw pointers to heap instances but this breaks the whole idea of using stack objects / RAII to manage resources. Is there way to use best of both worlds?

Comment: @barney If I understand you correctly, the "best of both worlds" is my alias code - `row` will only be a reference to the vector object inside `board`.

Comment: I think so. Afaik this reference to vector is already initialized and has its own elements in heap (0 elements) so row.resize() just creates enough space for x shared_ptr's in the heap and then allows to access them by index (operator[]) right? But what about shared pointers? They are being created at the resize and each time I do 
row[j] = piece; 
some memory is being copied. Is there any way to avoid this copying at all (as if I would use pPiece = new Piece(); and only memory that is moving is its pointer (4/8 bytes of pointer data) without any overhead of shared_ptr object fields

Comment: @barney Added an even more streamlined version.

Comment: Wow! This looks most elegant and effecient (according to emplace_back() method description) Thanks. It allows to perfectly forward the argument and construct an object directly into a container without temporary stack object at all!

Comment: Another question: I want to not create some corner pieces (just keep them as nullptr)

            if (0 == i || height-1 == i)
                if (0 == j || (width-1) == j) { // do not create corners
                    row.emplace_back(make_shared<Piece>(nullptr));
                    continue; 
                }

but looks like this make_shared<T>(nullptr) constructor is not found. It gives me ugly error from inside STL code

Comment: @barney `make_shared<T>(a,b, c)` means "dynamically create a new object of type `T` using `a, b, c` as constructor parameters." If you want a null pointer, don't use `make_shared`. Simply `row.emplace_back(nullptr);`.